# how to extract and modify inner array objects with parent object data in jq

Tags: json, jq

We are tying to format a json similar to this:

```json
[
{"id": 1,
    "type": "A",
    "changes": [ 
        {"id": 12},
        {"id": 13}
    ],
    "wanted_key": "good",
    "unwanted_key": "aaa"
},
{"id": 2,
    "type": "A",
    "unwanted_key": "aaa"
},
{"id": 3,
    "type": "B",
    "changes": [
        {"id": 31},
        {"id": 32}
    ],
    "unwanted_key": "aaa",
    "unwanted_key2": "aaa"
},
{"id": 4,
    "type": "B",
    "unwanted_key3": "aaa"
},
null,
null,
{"id": 7}
]
```

into something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "A",
    "wanted_key": true  # every record must have this key/value
  },
  {
    "id": 12,  # note: this was in the "changes" property of record id 1
    "type": "A",  # type should be the same type than record id 1
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 13,  # note: this was in the "changes" property of record id 1
    "type": "A",  # type should be the same type than record id 1
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "A",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "B",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 31,  # note: this was in the "changes" property of record id 3
    "type": "B",  # type should be the same type than record id 3
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 32,  # note: this was in the "changes" property of record id 3
    "type": "B",  # type should be the same type than record id 3
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "type": "B",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "type": "UNKN",  # records without a type should have this type
    "wanted_key": true
  }
]
```

So far, I've been able to:

- remove null records
- obtain the keys we need with their default
- give records without a type a default type

What we are missing:

- from records having a `changes` key, create new records with the `type` of their parent record
- join all records in a single array

Unfortunately we are not entirely sure how to proceed... Any help would be appreciated.

So far our jq goes like this:
`del(..|nulls) | map({id, type: (.type // "UNKN"), wanted_key: (true)}) | del(..|nulls)`

Here's our test code:

https://jqplay.org/s/eLAWwP1ha8P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
map(select(values))
| map(., .type as $type | (.changes[]? + {$type}))
| map({id, type: (.type // "UNKN"), wanted_key: true})
```

1. Only select non-null values
2. Return the original items followed by their inner changes array (+ outer type)
3. Extract 3 properties for output

Multiple `map` calls can usually be combined, so this becomes:

```
map(
    select(values)
    | ., (.type as $type | (.changes[]? + {$type}))
    | {id, type: (.type // "UNKN"), wanted_key: true}
)
```

---

Another option without variables:

```
map(
    select(values)
    | ., .changes[]? + {type}
    | {id, type: (.type // "UNKN"), wanted_key: true}
)
# or:
map(select(values))
| map(., .changes[]? + {type})
| map({id, type: (.type // "UNKN"), wanted_key: true})
```

or even with a separate normalization step for the unknown type:

```
map(select(values))
| map(.type //= "UNKN")
| map(., .changes[]? + {type})
| map({id, type, wanted_key: true})
# condensed to a single line:
map(select(values) | .type //= "UNKN" | ., .changes[]? + {type} | {id, type, wanted_key: true})
```

Explanation:

1. Select only non-null values from the array
2. If type is not set, create the property with value `"UNKN"`
3. Produce the original array items, followed by their nested changes elements extended with the parent type
4. Reshape objects to only contain properties id, type, and wanted_key.

Comment: In your last (condensed to a single line) version, `select(values).type //= "UNKN"` only filters out `null` values for the assignment, and keeps on processing the unfiltered set. Separate those two steps as in `select(values) | .type //= "UNKN"` in order to be equivalent to the uncondensed solution.

Comment: @pmf ah yes, thanks for noticing! I even had that version initially, but then removed the pipe again (operator/filter precedence can be a bit confusing at times with jq)

Comment: I'm gonna accept  your answer because of the explanations, but honestly, yours, pmf and Inian are all great, thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```bash
map(
  select(values)
  | (.type // "UNKN") as $type
  | ., .changes[]?
  | {id, $type, wanted_key: true}
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "A",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "type": "A",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "type": "A",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "A",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "B",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "type": "B",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "type": "B",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "type": "B",
    "wanted_key": true
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "type": "UNKN",
    "wanted_key": true
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YzLK0AAvQ7q)

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should work

```
map( 
  select(type == "object") | 
  ( {id}, {id : ( .changes[]? .id )} ) + 
  { type: (.type // "UNKN"), wanted_key: true }
)
```

jq play  - [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1NCswQyMUI3)